# Missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a local mobile services running at localhost. I try to call the service from a webpage running in the same solution, but on a different port.

The calling code looks like this.

```
    var MobileServiceClient = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient;
    var client = new MobileServiceClient('http://localhost:62541/', xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
    var table = client.getTable("todoitem");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#b").click(function () {
            table.read().done(function (result) {
                $("#t").text(JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            function (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            });
```

And my controller in my mobile service looks like this.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RequiresAuthorization(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]
public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
```

I get the following error when calling my service using the code above.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62541/tables/todoitem. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:60111' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I supply the missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header from my service?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130993/enable-cors-in-azure-mobile-services-options-not-authorized